# Config file from file system for apache camel quickfix application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-quickfix

I'm trying to read cfg file from file system but I couldn't find any example. Is it possible to create a route like that: Reading the config file from application.properties(it's a spring boot application)

```
from("quickfix:{{XX.config.file}}").routeId("XXFixRoute")
```

application.properties:

```
XX.config.file=/home/user/fixApp/XXconfig.cfg
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No it can only be loaded from classpath. The code is loading the config file is here: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quickfix/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/quickfixj/QuickfixjEngine.java#L253

But it could be a nice enhancement to allow to load the resource from file or classpath, as some of the other Camel components can do. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel issue tracker: http://camel.apache.org/support.html